# Datepicker: value not recognized as a date object by DateAdapter

Tags: angular, datepicker, angular2-forms, angular-material2

I get this error each time I save my form.
`Datepicker: value not recognized as a date object by DateAdapter. at MdDatepickerInput.set [as value]`

This is the input datepicker.

```
    <md-input-container>
        <input mdInput
               (dateChange)="saveForm()"
               placeholder="Event Date"
               [mdDatepicker]="eventDatePicker"
               formControlName="eventDate"
               [(ngModel)]="editingFundraiser.eventDate"/>
        <md-datepicker-toggle mdSuffix [for]="eventDatePicker"></md-datepicker-toggle>
        <md-datepicker #eventDatePicker></md-datepicker>
    </md-input-container>
```

This is the form in the ts file

```
private initForm() {
    this.myForm = this.fb.group({
        eventDate: new FormControl(this.editingForm.eventDate, Validators.required),
    });
}
```

This is the model for the form

```
export class MyForm
    eventDate: any;
}
```

I've read multiple articles and I've tried creating a custom date adapter to no avail.  Can anyone assist me with this issue?

Comment: what value you're retrieving from server? It has be to date object

Comment: I receive a date object from the server.  It appears that the `[(ngModel)]` is causing the problem @PankajParkar but I can't remove it because I need it to save the value

Comment: @Rafael I see that you already solved this, but are you sure `eventDate` is a Date object? If it's coming strait from your API, it's probably an ISO8601 string. Those will probably be supported directly [in the next release](https://github.com/angular/material2/pull/7091).

Comment: @WillHowell I think it is an ISO8601 string.

Comment: @Rafael we typically convert them with `new Date(val)` right when they're loaded from the api and then just pass around the date object so that all the datepickers work without issue. But it's annoying, so hopefully the native support for ISO8601 will come soon,

Answer (score 0):

I created a new function to solve my issue.

```
</md-input-container>        
    <input mdInput
           (dateChange)="saveDate($event)"
           placeholder="Event Date"
           [mdDatepicker]="eventDatePicker"
           formControlName="eventDate"/>
    <md-datepicker-toggle mdSuffix [for]="eventDatePicker"></md-datepicker-toggle>
    <md-datepicker #eventDatePicker></md-datepicker>
</md-input-container>
```

I passed in the event.value into this function and ran the save function at the end

```
saveDate(event) {
   this.editingFundraiser.eventDate = new Date(event.value);
   this.saveForm();
}
```